# Mark the maximum deviation/distance between curves

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just want to mark where the maximum deviation is occurred between two curves using matplotlib. Please help me.

The vertical distance is for the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

```
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
#------------------------------------
data=np.random.uniform(low=1,high=10,size=300)
standardized_data=np.sort(data-np.mean(data))/np.std(data)
probs=np.arange(1.0, 301)/300
plt.plot(standardized_data,probs) #curve1
plt.plot(stats.norm.ppf(probs),probs) #curve2
plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

like this 
[image]

or like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to interpolate one of the curves on the x values of the other. Then find the maximum of their difference.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
#------------------------------------
data=np.random.uniform(low=1,high=10,size=300)
x1= np.sort(data-np.mean(data))/np.std(data)
y = np.arange(1.0, 301)/300

x2 = stats.norm.ppf(y)
yc = np.interp(x1, x2, y)

ind_max = np.argmax((yc-y)**2)


plt.plot(x1, y) #curve1
plt.plot(x2, y) #curve2

plt.axvline(x1[ind_max], color="red", linestyle="dashed", alpha=0.4)
plt.plot([x1[ind_max], x1[ind_max]], [y[ind_max], yc[ind_max]], color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what exactly I'm looking for.